# Need to Loop Copy each row a set number of times based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following code which I am using to loop through a worksheet. Each row needs to be copied a certain number of times and the new rows pasted at the bottom, after the last row that currently has any text. The number of rows to copy for each present row is in the cell for column BU of that row. 
Hence, in order to do this, I have created the following loop to move through each row and use the cell value in column BU to copy cells in columns A through BT, then paste after the last active visible row.
However, it's not working well.

Any thought?

```
Sub Transfer()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long, lngRows
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Long

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Forecasted Movement")
With wsSource
rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- modifed this line

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To rowCount
    If .Cells(i, "BU").Value > 0 Then

        lngRows = .Cells(i, "BU").Value

       Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 72)).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        wsSource.Cells(lastrow, 1).Resize(lngRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues



    End If
Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "What does "it's not working well" mean? It would be easier to move the rows to a new sheet.

Comment: it also won't work as intended because `lastRow` will always change with each time rows are copied. So, place the line that sets that variable inside the for loop. Also, if you use the `specialcells` method and only paste values directly against the range, any hidden columns will be missed

Comment: What is `sht` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all in the same worksheet ( as the code suggests) the your lastrow is your problem.  You need to recalculate it everytime you paste a new row.

```
Sub Transfer()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long, lngRows


Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Long

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Forecasted Movement")
With wsSource
rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- modifed this line

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To rowCount
    If .Cells(i, "BU").Value > 0 Then

        lngRows = .Cells(i, "BU").Value

       Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 72)).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1  ' recalculate this for the next blank row
        wsSource.Cells(lastrow, 1).Resize(lngRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues



    End If
Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```